# Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Mvc\ApplicationInterface' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\book_sel\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php on line 51

Tags: interface, zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2 with `xampp` server for php but while running my index file I get the error as follows:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Mvc\ApplicationInterface' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\book_sel\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php on line 51

Please help me with it.

Comment: Check your installation and your autoloading. `Zend\Mvc\ApplicationInterface.php` is in the same directory as the file that can't find it. So either it's not there or your autoloading is messed up. It is very highly recommended to use the Skeleton application and composer to resolve the dependencies. At least until you get a solid handle on this beast, it's not a trivial exercise to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely best to install the application using composer as outlined here:

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

this will take care of any autoloading issues for you.

an example:

```
cd my/project/dir
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
cd ZendSkeletonApplication
php composer.phar install
```